# Pharaoh claiming he is god

Tags: prophet-musa

In one TV series, this was being told, something I have never heard before, and thought the script writers combined various facts and narrations into one mix as they saw fit. Still, I would ask whether it has been mentioned anywhere (it could be the case that it has been borrowed from Jewish narrations):

So the Pharaoh asks Moses, “Who is your Lord?” and Moses replied, “My Lord gives life and takes life.” Pharaoh asked for slaves. He gave a bag of gold to one, and killed the other, and said: “I gave life to one, killed the other, I am the Lord!” And Moses, showing the dead man, said, “Then give life to this one!”

Comment: Are you sure the speech was about Musa? Because the wording matches more the conversation between Ibraheem and the King Namrud in [2:258](https://legacy.quran.com/2/258). While Pharao is quoted for example in [79:24](https://legacy.quran.com/79/24) and in [28:38](https://legacy.quran.com/28/38)

Comment: That is why I said I thought the script writers simply mixed things to make it perhaps more interesting, or perhaps they did not do their homework; still I wanted to double-check.